# jprofile : how to indentify why this memory in application keep incresing in its (application's) ideal mode

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, profiling, quartz-scheduler, jprofiler

i have run JProfiler on one of our applicaiont:

this is the **JProfiler > Telemetries > Memory** snapshot :

[image]

You can see at last four high slowly increasing memory is when application is in IDEAL mode. I was not able to figure it out why this is happening. Can any one help me to find some more details.

We are using SpringMVC, Hibernate, DWR, Quartz (for sheduling) and other as common (common logging).

Edit:

This Increase memory in application's ideal mode is of mainly char[] and int[]. I have got this from   **Jprofiler > Live Memory > All Objects**. You can see here :

[image]

And I am not able to **Record This objects**. I have tried to get more details but not able to do so and when i am trying char[] Right Click >  Show Selection In Heap Walker : then it show only few KBs. You can see here:

[image]

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

This a temporary memory consumption which is difficult to analyze. There may be lots of short-lived objects that do not show up in a heap snapshot.

One way to keep track of created objects is to use the "Memory->Recorded Objects" view and invoke

View->Change Liveness Mode->Garbage Collected Objects

from the menu (or the tool bar). After the memory is released, you analyze the cumulative statistics on the short-lived objects that have been garbage collected.

To see where those objects were allocated, you can right click rows and selected "Show Allocation Tree" or "Show Allocation Hotspots" from the context menu.